# "import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" The import org.codehaus cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

so I am new to Java. I am trying to import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper. But Eclipse keeps givine me the error"The import org.codehaus cannot be resolved". Installed Java JDK 8. What does that mean? Any other information needed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ObjectMapper is not a JDK class, it is from a third party library. So the obvious question here is whether you have the library set-up in eclipse, whether is it on your build path, ...? Are you using Maven to manage dependencies?

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace ?

Comment: if your problem is all about jar files [try to find it on this site](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Aorg.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper)

Comment: I downloaded the jar file and added it to the library. It did solve the problem. Thanks a lot!